# Grafana, how to transform time column from timestamp to date

Tags: grafana

I am trying to use transformation "Convert field type" to strip time from timestamp,
but it seems not to work as I expect. Any idea how to get rid of time?
I need only date in order to group by day

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to have a single line per day, you can use `GROUP BY time(1d)` in your query.

To hide the time part inside of the label, define an Override:

[image]

Comment: Yes this works in v10.1.1. Had to rotate the labels -45 degrees otherwise they are messed up. Couldn't get it right even when setting the X-axis labels minimum spacing...

Answer (score 1):

You need to format the time as a string, there you can specify the format you want

[image: time as string]